# How to take a collection of data from a c# api and turn it into a array in angular

Tags: c#, angular

I have a working .Net Core api. I am trying to use a http get request in angular to get a collection of data, and am trying to find out how to turn that collection into an array in angular.

I've tried setting the value to an array that accepts any and I cant seem to find any answers for this out there.

```
export class GamesComponent implements OnInit {
  games;

  constructor(public gamesService: GamesService) { 

  }

  ngOnInit(){
    console.log(this.gamesService.getGames());
    var arr: any[]
    arr = this.gamesService.getGames();
    this.games = arr;
  }

}


export class GamesService {
  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {

   }

   getGames(){
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
    var games = this.http.get(`https://LOCALHOST/api/games`, {headers:headers}).toPromise();
    return games;
   }
}
```

I am expecting the result from my get request to go into an array in my component that I can use.`enter code here`

Comment: it depends on which format your api returns the collection in. Is it JSON format?

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: I would expect `games` to be a Promise object, rather than the actual result itself. To collect the result, attach a `.done()` or `.then()` callback to the promise object. If you don't understand yet how Promises work, now would be a good time to find a tutorial. [this one](https://vitalflux.com/angular-http-promise-code-example-get-api/) helpfully shows examples in the context of Angular's http.get method, which you're using here.

Answer (score 1):

since the service returns a promise you can `await` the call and get the result.

```
async ngOnInit(){ this.games =  await this.gamesService.getGames(); }
```